# How to save multiple phone numbers into phone using objective c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, contacts

I am trying to create a simple app where I will get a JSON with contact details like name, number, and email. So when I click a button I want all these numbers saved in my phone.

I have tried to parse JSON and put contact saving code in a loop to save but I am not able to see new contacts

**my JSON format**

```
[ {
        "Name": "name1",
        "mobile": 8634003462503653464,
        "email": "email01@gmail.com"
    },
    {
        "Name": "name2",
        "mobile": 912343576655686,
        "email": "email@yahoo.co.in"
    }
]
```

**Code**

```
- (IBAction)button:(id)sender {


NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"test" ofType:@"json"];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
NSMutableArray *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:nil];
//NSLog(@"%@", json);

CNContactStore *store = [[CNContactStore alloc] init];

// create contact

CNMutableContact *contact = [[CNMutableContact alloc] init];

for(NSDictionary *dict in json){
    //NSLog(@"%@", dict);
    //NSLog(@"name %@",dict[@"Name"]);

    NSString *finalname = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ Marketing",dict[@"Name"]];
    contact.familyName = dict[@"Name"];
    contact.givenName = finalname;
    CNLabeledValue *homePhone = [CNLabeledValue labeledValueWithLabel:CNLabelHome value:[CNPhoneNumber phoneNumberWithStringValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"+91%@",dict[@"mobile"]]]];
    contact.phoneNumbers = @[homePhone];


    CNContactViewController *controller = [CNContactViewController viewControllerForUnknownContact:contact];
    controller.contactStore = store;
    controller.delegate = self;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:TRUE];
}


}
```

So here I have 500+ contact list in JSON and I am trying to save all these contacts in my phone over a button click

Comment: You need to use [`CNSaveRequest`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/contacts/cnsaverequest) not `CNContactViewController`

Comment: in swift its working

Comment: I don't see how. This code attempts to present numerous `CNContactViewController` instances.  Even if it did work it would be a UI nightmare; the user would need to manually save each contact.

Comment: Agree with Paulw11, you might only want to display a view controller if you wanted to update an existing contact, and you need the user to select the contact to update.  Otherwise, you want to create a New contact, and then populate its values, then Save the request without displaying any UI component.  However, you probably have to check to see if permission has been granted before doing any of these things.

Comment: See this line `[self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:TRUE];` you are about to push ViewController 500+ times. This is UI disaster, app will rejected by Apple.

Answer (score 0):

You can update the contact below way. You don't need `CNContactViewController` .

```
CNSaveRequest * saveRequest = [[CNSaveRequest alloc]init];
[saveRequest updateContact:contact];
NSError *updateError = nil;
[store executeSaveRequest:saveRequest error:&updateError];
```